# startActivityForResult to create pending notification triggering immediately

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-notifications

I have the following code with two activities where I have a ListActivity in MainActivity then AddItemsActivity to dynamically add items to the ListActivity. I'm stuck on one part of it and I'm not sure if it is easier to fix the current code or if I should go about it a different way programmatically.

**My goal is when the data is sent from AddItemActivity to MainActivity a PendingIntent notification is generated which will fire off on the day selected.**

I have been searching Google and here at SO for about a week trying various proposed solutions and nothing seems to handle it how I need.

I understand that I will eventually need some way to save the generated notifications in some storage format but for the moment I just want to verify the functionality works correctly.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    static final int ADD_ITEM_REQUEST = 1; // ActivityForResult request code

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ...
    } 

    // addItems is defined in XML Button onClick
    public void addItems(View view) {
        /* Start Activity For Result */
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddItemActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, ADD_ITEM_REQUEST);
    }

    // Activity Result passed from AddItemActivity
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // Check which request to respond to
    if (requestCode == ADD_ITEM_REQUEST) {
        // Make sure the result was successful
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if ((data.getExtras().containsKey("editTextView") && !data.getStringExtra("editTextView").isEmpty()) && data.getExtras().containsKey("textView") && !data.getStringExtra("textView").isEmpty()) {
                // HashMap defines and sets Intent extras to ListActivity items
                HashMap<String, String> temp = new HashMap<>();
                temp.put("editTextView", data.getStringExtra("editTextView"));
                temp.put("textView", data.getStringExtra("textView"));
                list.add(temp) // list is instance of ListAdapter

                ... // what (if anything) could go here?
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "An Error Has Occurred", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // notifies ListAdapter of changes
    }
  }
}
```

AddItemActivity.java

```
public class AddItemActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    EditText itemNameET;
    Button setDateBtn;
    TextView dateView;
    private Calendar calendar;
    private int year, month, day;

    private PendingIntent pendingIntent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_item);

        itemNameET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editItemText);
        setDateBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.setDateButton);

        dateView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.setDateTextView);
        calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        showDate(year, month, day);
    }

    public void sendToListView(View view) {
        // Set result on AddItemActivity
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
        // Add extras or a data URI to this intent as appropriate.
        resultIntent.putExtra("editTextView", itemNameET.getText().toString()); // Item title
        resultIntent.putExtra("textView", dateView.getText().toString()); // Date
        resultIntent.putExtra("passDateYear", year); // Selected Year
        resultIntent.putExtra("passDateMonth", month); // Selected Month
        resultIntent.putExtra("passDateDay", day); // Selected Day

        Intent myIntent = new Intent(AddItemActivity.this, DateReceiver.class);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(AddItemActivity.this, 0, myIntent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
        // Toast.makeText(this, "New Item Added Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Date Passed: " + calendar.getTimeInMillis(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
        finish();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void setDate(View view) { // Button onClick action
        showDialog(999);
    }

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (id == 999) {
            return new DatePickerDialog(this, myDateListener, year, month, day);
        }
        return null;
    }

    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener myDateListener
        = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            // arg1 = year
            // arg2 = month
            // arg3 = day
            showDate(arg1, arg2+1, arg3);
        }
    };

    private void showDate(int year, int month, int day) {
        dateView.setText(new StringBuilder().append(month).append("/").append(day).append("/").append(year));
    }
}
```

DateReceiver.java (BroadcastReceiver)

```
public class DateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent service1 = new Intent(context, DateAlarmService.class);
        context.startService(service1);
    }
}
```

DateAlarmService (Service)

```
public class DateAlarmService extends Service {
    private NotificationManager notificationManager;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        super.onStart(intent, startId);

        notificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(this.getApplicationContext().NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Intent intent1 = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);

    Notification notification = new Notification(R.mipmap.ic_launcher, "Test!", System.currentTimeMillis());
    intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    PendingIntent pendingNotificationIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this.getApplicationContext(), 0, intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;


    notification.setLatestEventInfo(this.getApplicationContext(), "Test", "Test!", pendingNotificationIntent);
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND; // notification sound
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS; // notification lights
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE; // notification vibration


    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
}
```

The code provided creates a notification as soon as onActivityResult begins even if I set the calendar date for one or more days ahead.

Comment: So what is the issue? you set the alarm to tomorrow and it fires today? Or you set it to yesterday and it fires today?

Comment: You have posted too much code, but what I see is you are setting an alarm at current time, see `calendar.getTimeInMillis()` in `alarmManager.set()`, there you need to set the time you want the alarm to be triggered.

Comment: @DerGolem what happens is if I set an alarm say for any time, it immediately fires off the notification (regardless of the day set) as soon as the data is passed to the onActivityResult method.

Comment: The alarm will fire immediately if the date is already due.

Comment: @Apurva I tried adding a set method in the setResult method (sendToListView) using `calendar.set(year, month, day);` but regardless of the dates chosen it sets the date to generate the notification to the time I save the information.

Comment: you are not setting the year, month, date correctly and that's why it doesn't work as you want. I have written the mistake you make and also a solution in my answer, check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are setting an alarm is **wrong.** You are **setting an alarm at current system time** and that's the reason it gets triggered as you set it.

To set the alarm you are using `calendar.getTimeInMillis()` in `alarmManager.set()` and you initializes your calendar as,

```
calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

Which is the current time, not the desired time you want to set, and that's why alarm fires as you set it.

**To set the alarm at the specific time**, first set the desired `time` and/or `date` in the calendar as,

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2015);
calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, 3);
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 18);
```

and set the alarm as,

```
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

Which will trigger an alarm on `March 18, 2015` i.e. on tomorrow.

Set your desired year, month and day values in `calendar.set()` to fire alarm at the time you want.

Comment: Now I understand what the difference is that you put. Now the problem I'm running into is that I need to figure out a way to set the value for Calendar YEAR, MONTH, and DAY_OF_MONTH by means of the variables `private int year, month, day` since the user will be picking an arbitrary date through the Calendar function.

Comment: Success!!! I am going to mark your answer correct because it was vital to the program working! What I had to do was add a line of code to the `onDateSet` function. What I added to the end of the method was `int newYear = arg1; int newMonth = arg2; int newDay = arg3;` then in the `sendToListView` method I used your code and replaced the values with the new variables. Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell you are setting your alarm to ring at the current system time.

Whenever you call `Calendar.getInstance()`, it returns a `Calendar` object set to the current date and time. You have to call one of the `set` methods on the returned `Calendar` instance at least once before you call `alarmManager.set`.

Comment: As I have mentioned above, no matter what date I set using `calendar.set(year, month, day)` the date set to create the notification is the moment I save the data. So if I click the save button to send the data to the list at 1:00 PM today 3/17 then the date/time the notification displays at is 1:00 PM on 3/17/15. No matter what I do the date will not get set to any day/time other than today.